# What could cause excessively long query times when using a table created by insert into?

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-insert, sql-server-2016

So our situation is that we want to retrieve a number of tables off client databases to do analysis on (this is about 20 out of 2500 tables in their database). I have written a script and created some instructions (see answer on [Export tables in SSMS and import them onto a different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59781099/export-tables-in-ssms-and-import-them-onto-a-different-server) for how I have done that) to get the client to set up a new database and use the script to use insert into in order to move all tables across to this new database (which they will then backup and send to us).

I have done this with one database and it all worked fine, however, when I came to the second database (different database structure, so modified the script) I am having issues. The script runs fine and then I can see all the data in the tables, I can then create a set of views fine (on a separate database) but there is one particular view (which I can not share the code of here for confidentiality reasons) that takes around four and a half to five minutes to run (this is when I use the right click in SSMS and select top 1000 rows).

The strange thing is, that with EXACTLY the same code used to create the view, but pointing back to the original database instead of the one that was created with the insert into, took 5 seconds to run. So there has to be something happening when I use the insert into. There should be no index's etc required to come across (the database doesn't use relationships, these are created inside of the app), so not sure where else to look.

I have mucked around with the SQL to set up the view, and there are 2 parts I can disable to make it work fine, the strange thing is I can comment out either part and it works fine, but the 2 parts are not related in any way (look at different fields etc). Seems totally random, maybe a glitch in SQL server? We are using the latest SQL Server 2016.

Has anyone else had similar issues with "INSERT INTO" results?

Comment: SQL Server performance questions are never able to be answered in general, they are always very specific to the query and database configuration. Your best bet is to generate the execution plan and see where SQL Server is spending its time.

Comment: And once the question is more specific you may find better expertise over at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OK, have done execution plans on both views and compared and they seem similar. The insert into lost some keys, so I started looking at the missing index part and adding keys back in and found there was 1 table that when the primary key is not specified it was making the difference. This is one that the primary key shouldn't have mattered anyhow, but I will just manually specify it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after running execution plans I started to add primary keys back in and found one particular table killed the execution time when the primary key wasn't specified (which none would be as I used INSERT INTO). I would suggest to anyone in future, compare the data in the original database for primary keys and replicate that into the database you inserted into until you reduce the view load time. Hope this can help someone in future.

Comment: You can't just dump data into heaps and expect good performance. An obvious starting point (as you learned) is to create the same indexes as the source database. But tuning will likely need to be done afterwards. You don't really need the PKs and FKs but you do need the associated indexes.